# Заменить ' 0.00 ' на ' - ' при отображении данных из запроса

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
update #v2 set [Prihod]='-' where [Prihod]='0,00'
```

Не работает.

Как есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Prihod] какого типа? вы путаете отображение и хранение значений

Comment: @Konst, [Prihod] - тип данных money

Comment: тогда ваш код update неверный. вам нужно делать выборку на экран(приложение) или вы просто экспериментируете в SSMS?

Comment: @Konst, да, нужно сделать выборку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @t table(Prihod money);

insert into @t (Prihod)
values (20000), (10000), (0), (0);

select  case when t.Prihod = 0 then '-' else CONVERT(varchar(20), t.Prihod) end as PrihodString from @t t
```

а вообще, отображением и форматированием должно заниматься клиентское приложение